# Bolt of electric shock on upper right chest

Tags: pain

Sometimes when I get excited about something or having a good laugh, suddenly in the middle of this excitement, I feel a moderate bolt of electric shock (usually lasts 2-4 seconds) on the upper right side of my chest, that interrupts my excitement. This happened quite a few number of times and so I was thinking I should consult a physician. But before I consult one, I thought I should research if this problem is really a serious one... Why do you think this happens? Is it something more serious?

Comment: Hi Ritu, and welcome to health.SE. We are not able to address personal medical issues such as this here. Please take this to your own doctor who knows you and can do an examination and review your history in order to make a proper diagnosis. Thanks.

Comment: @Susan Hi Susan, I do intend to visit my doctor. I asked this question so that I have at least a slight idea about the background of the problem before I visit him. Its okay if I don't get an answer here as I will see my doctor soon. Thanks..